# ActiveRecord query with find_by_sql on postgis data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

To date, I have only been able to run a find_by_sql query involving all records of two tables to find Intersects.

```
Regionpolygon.where('nation_id = ?', 74).find_by_sql "SELECT regionpolygons.id, area_name, destinations.id 
  FROM regionpolygons, destinations 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(regionpolygons.polygon_area, destinations.latlon)"
```

Two goals which need to be achieved are:

- having a smaller subset from which to query regionpolygons  `@rps = Regionpolygon.where('nation_id = ?',74).all`  This appears to work..
- providing a single point from the destinations table `@dests = Destination.all  @dests.each do |dest|  [...]` so that an iteration can allow for updating record attributes 
  instance variables do not appear to be well digested when added to this type of query

How can this query be formulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but it you are just looking for a manageable and programmatic way to generate that query then, you could perform this search with `arel` as follows

```
rp_table = Regionpolygon.arel_table
destination_table = Destination.arel_table

query = rp_table.project(rp_table[:id], 
           rp_table[:area_name], 
           destination_table[:id].as('destination_id')
   ).join(destination_table).on(
       Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ST_Intersects', 
         [rp_table[:polygon_area], destination_table[:latlon]]
       )
   ).where(rp_table[:nation_id].eq(74))
```

This will produce the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [regionpolygons].[id], 
    [regionpolygons].[area_name], 
    [destinations].[id] AS destination_id 
FROM 
    [regionpolygons] 
    INNER JOIN [destinations] ON 
        ST_Intersects([regionpolygons].[polygon_area], [destinations].[latlon])     
WHERE 
    [regionpolygons].[nation_id] = 74
```

You can convert `query` to SQL by literally calling `to_sql`. So:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query.to_sql).to_hash
```

Will return an `Array` of the rows it found performing the above where the rows are converted to hashes. This hash will look like:

```
 {"id" => 1, "area_name" => "area_name", "destination_id" => 1}
```

Comment: since the goal is to iterate over a collection, I modified the where clause to `).where(rp_table[:nation].eq(74).and(destination_table[:id].eq(4079)))`.  Very clear and thus useful answer; *I had totally glossed over AREL, yet wonder why find_by_sql was so 'unscoped' ...*